# New filter expression QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, filter, expression

I try the new filter expression with QGIS 2.8. I want to filter only the selected objects on a layer in my map. My expression is:

```py
import processing
from qgis.core import * 
vlayer = processing.getObject('mylayer')
selected_objects = vlayer.selectedFeatures()`
```

I save this expression but I can't open QGIS after.

`Error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatures"`

Comment: It just means that vlayer is null (no layer)

Comment: The layer exist and no problem in Python console

Answer (score 2):

If you type in the Python Console these **help** commands:

```
help(processing.getObject)
Help on function getObject in module processing.tools.dataobjects:

getObject(uriorname)

help(QgsVectorLayer.select)
Help on built-in function select:

select(...)
    QgsVectorLayer.select(QgsRectangle, bool)
    QgsVectorLayer.select(int)
    QgsVectorLayer.select(unknown-type)

help(QgsVectorLayer.selectedFeatures)
Help on built-in function selectedFeatures:

selectedFeatures(...)
    QgsVectorLayer.selectedFeatures() -> list-of-QgsFeature
```

You can observe that if your 'uiorname' is correct you should first select the features with 'select'.

This code works well in my system:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import * 
vlayer = processing.getObject('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/world_borders.shp')

list=[501, 967, 3171]

for item in list:
    vlayer.select(item)

selected_objects = vlayer.selectedFeatures()

print selected_objects
```

for this shapefile with selected features by index 501, 967 and 3171:

[image]

where printed references to selected features objects were:

```
execfile(u'/home/zeito/scriptspyqgis/selected.py'.encode('UTF-8'))
[<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0xc6f2b6c>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0xc6f2a94>, 
<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0xc6f2a4c>]
```

Comment: I agree that it works the way you did it. But, did you try it in the new function editor in the expression filter (QGIS 2.8)? Can't open QGIS after save this expression)